# export table with number written in scientific notation

Tags: output-formatting

I am trying to write on a file the table generated in this way:

```
error = ConstantArray[0, 3];
error[[1]] = ScientificForm[Sqrt[CovMat[[1, 1]] /. out[[2]]]];
error[[2]] = ScientificForm[Sqrt[CovMat[[2, 2]] /. out[[2]]]];
error[[3]] = ScientificForm[Sqrt[CovMat[[3, 3]] /. out[[2]]]];
Ris = out[[2]] /. Rule -> (#2 &);
par = out[[2]] /. Rule -> (#1 &);
Finale = MapThread[{#1, ScientificForm[#2], #3} &, {par, Ris, 
    error}] // TableForm
```

CovMat anf out are generated in a previoous part of the code (a `NMinimize`). Typing Finale on the notebook I find:

```
M   4.35203*10^(10) 4.2566*10^(9)
\[Delta]    4.10847*10^(5)  2.12356*10^(4)
L   1.01689*10^(9)  1.30717*10^(16)
```

The problem is that in the file I find:

```
"M  ScientificForm[1.7467449664329874*^11]  \
ScientificForm[4.784135569792907*^9]

[\Delta]    ScientificForm[606745.0359163599]   \
ScientificForm[10326.21966853348]

L   ScientificForm[2.788541796939519*^10]   \
ScientificForm[1.5410843643505646*^18]"
```

I used `Export` and

```
file = OpenAppend["out.txt"]

string = ExportString[Finale,"Table"];

WriteString[file, string]
WriteString[file, "\n"];

Close[file]
```

(I thought that `ExportString` read the values as they are) but I cannot get rid of that `ScientificForm`.

I suspect that I should use something like:

```
Export["file.dat", {elem1->expr1, elem2->expr2, ...}, "Rules"]
```

but I cannot find a way to express the rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why your file looks like that

As we can read at the end of of "Details and Options" section of [ScientificForm documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScientificForm.html):

> ScientificForm acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not
>   evaluation.

So although

```
In[1]:=  ScientificForm[410846.99999999994`]
```

is outputted as

```
Out[1]//ScientificForm=
          4.10847 x 10^5
```

under the hood it is still number `` 410846.99999999994` `` wrapped with `ScientificForm`:

```
In[2]:=  ScientificForm[410846.99999999994`] // FullForm
Out[2]//FullForm=
          ScientificForm[410846.99999999994`]
```

This number wrapped with `ScientificForm` when exported to `"Table"` format is somehow converted to a string:

```
In[3]:=  ExportString[ScientificForm[410846.99999999994`],"Table"]
Out[3]:= ScientificForm[410846.99999999994]
```

From simple experiment:

```
In[4]:=  Block[{ToString = toString}, ExportString[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, "Table"]]
Out[4]:= toString[a, InputForm]    toString[b, InputForm]
          toString[c, InputForm]    toString[d, InputForm]
```

we see that `ToString[#, InputForm]&` is used and, as one would expect, in input form we have:

```
In[5]:=  ToString[ScientificForm[410846.99999999994`], InputForm]
Out[5]:= ScientificForm[410846.99999999994`]
```

This is the reason behind output you're getting.

### How to get what you want

What you want is to convert numbers wrapped with `ScientificForm` to strings in `OutputForm` not in `InputForm`. Since `OutputForm` is default form of `ToString` we don't specify any form:

```
In[6]:=  ScientificForm[410846.99999999994`] // ToString
Out[6]:=              5
          4.10847 x 10
```

It's not exactly what we want, but since "ordinary" `*.dat` file has no support for superscripts we need to change our scientific form a bit, to take that into account. We can do that using [NumberFormat](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberFormat.html?q=NumberFormat&lang=en) option:

```
In[7]:=  ScientificForm[410846.99999999994`, NumberFormat -> (#1 <> "*10^(" <> #3 <> ")" &)] // ToString
Out[7]:= "4.10847*10^(5)"
```

That's of course just an example you can customize it to suit your needs.

Going back to your particular case. Start with your table containing "raw" numbers not wrapped with any formating function:

```
In[8]:=  data = {
             {M, 4.35203*10^(10), 4.2566*10^(9)},
             {δ, 4.10847*10^(5), 2.12356*10^(4)},
             {L, 1.01689*10^(9), 1.30717*10^(16)}
          };
```

and make appropriate conversion just before exporting:

```
In[9]:=  Export[
              "file.dat"
              ,
              data /. a_?NumberQ :> 
                  ToString@ScientificForm[a, NumberFormat -> (#1 <> "*10^(" <> #3 <> ")" &)]
          ]
Out[9]:= file.dat
```

this produces following `file.dat` file:

```
M   4.35203*10^(10)  4.2566*10^(9)
δ   4.10847*10^(5)   2.12356*10^(4)
L   1.01689*10^(9)   1.30717*10^(16)
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation and accept. Thank you!