# How to directly use formatted numbers (e.g. AccountingForm) in calculations?

Tags: output-formatting, number-representation

The documentation for [`AccountingForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccountingForm.html) states:

> AccountingForm acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not evaluation.

However,

```
x = AccountingForm[1500.12, {7, 2}, DigitBlock -> 3];
x/2
```

> ```
> 1,500.12 / 2
> ```

Where `1,500.12` is not resolved to its number and `750.06` is not returned as either a number nor an `AccountingForm` number.  What does the documentation statement mean?  It appears that the formatting functions do affect evaluation as no evaluation occurs if a formatted number is used.  Bug or am I missing something?

Comment: This isn't just an `AccountingForm[]` thing, the line is repeated, for instance, in `NumberForm[]`.

Comment: @Feyre Yes, I am using `AccountingForm` as an example; hence the "e.g.".

Comment: quite recent: [**139366**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139366/5478)

Comment: yes its an annoying deficiency in the documentation.  Just think how much grief they would save newcomers (and us) with a few words to the effect that the results of "*Form" should not be used for further processing.

Comment: @george2079. That is not quite right. As long as you do not assign the Form expression to a symbol, you can further process the result. If by abuse you assigned the Form expression to a symbol, you can use the result by taking part 1.

Comment: I suppose its worth pointing out here `Out` ( ie `%` ) accesses  prior "results" without the "wrapper" if the previous expression is wrapped in a "*Form".  (also not well documented)

Answer (score 1):

[`AccountingForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccountingForm.html) and similar formatters are typeset with an [`InterpretationBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpretationBox.html):

> InterpretationBox[boxes, expr]
>   is a low-level box construct that displays as boxes but is interpreted on input as expr.

The internal "kernel" `FullForm` is still `AccountingForm[1500.12,...]`, but the box form in the front end is

```
Cell[BoxData[
 TagBox[
  InterpretationBox["\<\"1,500.12\"\>",
   1500.12,
   AutoDelete->True],
  AccountingForm[#, {7, 2}, DigitBlock -> 3]& ]], "Output",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.697810013552223*^9}]
```

When the expression is copied in the front end and pasted as input, the `InterpretationBox` is passed to the kernel and "interpreted," that is, the second argument `1500.12` is used for the value.

The OP's example, with the output copied as input:

[image]

One can do the same thing programmatically with

```
ToExpression@ToBoxes[x/2, StandardForm]
(*  750.06  *)
```

The upshot is that output-formatters are intended to be used for formatting output, not internally in computations.  At least, that seems to be the intention.

**Appendix**

I just noticed this subtlety:

[image]

If the output of the first line is typeset, then in the subsequent `%/2`, the `AccountingForm` is interpreted as a number; if the output suppressed with a semicolon, then the internal `FullForm` is used and `AccountingForm[..]` is left unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that they mean the evaluation of the arguments to `AccountingForm`.

```
x = AccountingForm[1500.12, {7, 2}, DigitBlock -> 3]
```

For sure you can not use `x` directly in a computation. This is clear if you look at the `FullForm`.

```
x/2 // FullForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Instead attempt to extract the numerical value:

```
(x /. AccountingForm[z_?NumericQ, y___] -> z)/2

(* 750.06 *)
```

**Fed Simons** commented that an easier way is to use `Part`.

```
x[[1]]/2

(* 750.06 *)
```

Comment: A little bit simpler: take `x[[1]]` if you want to get rid of the head `AccountingForm` of `x`.

Comment: @FredSimons Added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: If you want to retain the wrapper, use `ReplacePart[x, 1 -> x[[1]]/2]`