# ScientificForm in Dataset

Tags: output-formatting, dataset

Via SQL query I produce a list

```
dblist = {{"ID", "One", "Two"}, {"C1", 10.24, 1.1123456*^10}, {"C2", 
20.23, 1.9123456*^10}, {"C3", 3., 2.01123456*^10}, {"C4", 20.12, 
17123456.}, {"C5", Null, 25123456.}, {"C6", 20., Null}};
```

like this and convert it into a dataset:

```
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[First @ dblist, #] & /@ Rest@dblist]
```

[image]

Now, I'm rounding the values of "One" and produce a new dataset:

```
dblist[[All, 2]] = Round[dblist[[All, 2]], 1];
dblist[[1, 2]] = "One";
dsround = Dataset[AssociationThread[First @ dblist, #] & /@ Rest@dblist]
```

[image]

About the trouble with the `Null` I care later on. But now comes the part I don't understand. I'd like to write the values of "Two" in `ScientificForm` and ony one digit after the point. Hence, I apply the same procedure as before with the rounding:

```
dblist[[All, 3]] = ScientificForm[dblist[[All, 3]], 2];
dblist[[1, 3]] = "Two";
dsscform = Dataset[AssociationThread[First @ dblist, #] & /@ Rest@dblist]
```

But this does not work as expected:

[image]

Any ideas where my error in reasoning lies? 
Why do I get in every row the whole list?

I appreciate all hints and ideas.

Comment: You have written below, that you want to continue to work with the data. Why then use `Dataset` which is infering types for presentation purposes. I would suggest to work with `Association` and use `Dataset` when you are going for presentation -- here you can build yourself a constructor to produce a dataset with scientific form output. I would also suggest to replace `Null` with something like `Missing[]` which can be handled more easily.

Comment: @gwr: that's an intresting comment, I should think about my concept with the `Datasets` But only after my talk about the analysis next week...

Comment: If you have not done so, yet, have a look at: [(87360)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87360/764) and also [(146171)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146171/764).

Comment: Regarding the formatting of numbers take a look at [(8923)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8923/764).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By testing the attributes of `Round` and `ScientificForm`, `ScientificForm` is not `Listable`, so it shall not work on a list directly. try `Map` or  `/@`.

```
Attributes[Round]
```

> {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected}

```
Attributes[ScientificForm]
```

> {NHoldRest, Protected}

then, the upper codes could become like

```
dblist[[All, 3]] = ScientificForm[#, 2] & /@ dblist[[All, 3]];
(*dblist[[All,3]] = Map[ScientificForm[#,2]&,dblist[[All,3]]];*)
dblist[[1, 3]] = "Two";
dsscform = Dataset[AssociationThread[First@dblist, #] & /@ Rest@dblist]
```

> [image]

Or, I suggest make the best of operations on `Dataset` instead.

```
dblist = {{"ID", "One", "Two"}, {"C1", 10.24, 1.1123456*^10}, {"C2", 
20.23, 1.9123456*^10}, {"C3", 3., 2.01123456*^10}, {"C4", 20.12, 
17123456.}, {"C5", Null, 25123456.}, {"C6", 20., Null}};

(*dblist = dblist/. Null -> 0 *) (* replace Null values*)

ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[First @ dblist, #] & /@ Rest@dblist]
```

> [image]

firstly define operations

```
fRound[num_] := Round[num, 1]
fSciForm[num_] := ScientificForm[num, 2]
```

then appy them on columns of the dataset `ds`

```
ds[All, {"One" -> fRound, "Two" -> fSciForm}]
```

> [image]

Comment: The operations suggestion is very nice, this represents what I was searching for. And I think it is a very elegant solution in addition.

Comment: (+1) I would suggest to work with `Missing[]` instead of `Null` for obvious reasons: `ds // Query[All, { "One" -> ( Switch[#, Null, Missing[], _, Round[#]] &)
   , "Two" -> ( Switch[#, Null, Missing[], _, ScientificForm[#, 2]] &) }  ]`

Comment: @gwr  I already use `Missing[]` I just haven't described it above, should have avoided the `Null` in my example ;)

Comment: other question: at the moment I don't understand were the double quotes in the ScientificForm come from.

Comment: @Lea Because the result is merely a `Form`, made of strings. Try inputting `ScientificForm[10000.0,2]`, then select the output and from the Menu select [Cell]->[Show Cell Expression] you can get the essense.

Answer (score 2):

The output of `foo=ScientificForm[dblist[[All, 3]], 2]` looks like a list but if you run `Dimension[foo]` you do not get 7, but 2: because `ScientificForm` is a wrapper (think of it as a display mode, e.g. if `x= ScientificForm[1]` you cannot do the calculation such as `x+1`). More apparent if you run `FullForm[foo]`. Therefore,

```
nf = (#1 <> "*10^(" <> #3 <> ")" &);
dblist[[All, 3]] = 
  Map[ToString@ScientificForm[#, 2, NumberFormat -> nf] &, 
   dblist[[All, 3]]];
dblist[[1, 3]] = "Two";
dsscform = 
 Dataset[AssociationThread[First@dblist, #] & /@ Rest@dblist]
```

[image]

ref:
[export table with number written in scientific notation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48266/export-table-with-number-written-in-scientific-notation)

And, for the "One" column, you may try something like this to deal with the null:

```
dblist[[All, 2]] = 
  If[NumericQ[#], Round[#, 1], 
     If[# === Null, "doSomething", If[# == "One", "One"]]] & /@ 
   dblist[[All, 2]];
```

or just replace them in `dblist` first.

Comment: nice idea, but this only helps for presentation issues. I want to work further with those datasets, e.g via using cuts like this one: `test = ds[Select[#"Two" >= 1.9*^10 &]]`. This doesn't work with the ds = dsscform as proposed by you, while it still works when I use ds = dsround.

Answer (score 2):

In extension to my comments and to make the output a bit prettier:

```
ds // Query[All,
    {
        "One" -> ( Switch[#, Null, Missing[], _, Round[#]] &)
        , "Two" -> ( Switch[#, Null, Missing[], _, NumberForm[#, {2, 1}] ] &)
    }
]
```

[image: dataset]